# Plotting boxplots side-by-side per x variable

Tags: r, graph, sas, boxplot

I wanted some help regarding plotting boxplots side-by-side in R or SAS.

Background - I need to plot a y-variable vs an x-variable by group Z. Currently I am able to plot them separately ([Existing_PLot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ACWE.png)) by group Z in SAS.

The requirement is to achieve as per the snapshot attached ([Required_Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R88Em.png)).

My code in SAS:

```
proc sgpanel data=example; 
   panelby groups; 
   vbox y / category=x group=groups; 
run;
```

Comment: Could you please share your code with some dummy data, and indicate what you've already attempted? Also, please take a look [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/ggplot2-package.html).

Comment: @Dunois Yes of course! I used the following code in SAS to create the "existing_plot" - proc sgpanel data=example; panelby groups; vbox y / category=x group=groups; run;

Answer (score 1):

What you need can be reached using data in long format keeping an id variable for the x-axis and moving the remaining variables as rows. As no data is included, I have done an example using `iris`, `tidyverse` functions and `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
data(iris)
#Code
iris %>% pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Species,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(fill='Var')+
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'top',
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))+
  labs(x='Node',fill='Variable')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @snanavati Great!

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the default in SAS with PROC SGPLOT.  PROC SGPANEL exists specifically to do what you showed in your first example - but the normal proc is SGPLOT and it does what you ask.

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.cars;
  vbox mpg_city/category=type group=origin;
run;
```